# React Props Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, react-props

I am working on the React Recipe Box project from Free Code Camp. I have a parent component that displays recipe names, which it receives as props. The recipe name can be clicked to display a child component that then has the same props passed down to the child component to display information about the ingredients. My problem is, when I click the recipe name, the props in the parent component become undefined. Ive googled a bunch, but I cant figure out why this is happening. Has anyone run into this before?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ShowRecipe from './recipeDetail';


class RecipeDetail extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isHidden:true
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
          <h5>

            <button
              className="btn btn-link"
              onClick={() => {
                this.setState({isHidden: !this.state.isHidden})
              }} 
            >
              {this.props.recipe.recipeName}
            </button>

          </h5>
        </div>

        { !this.state.isHidden &&
          <ShowRecipe
            ingredients={this.props.recipe.ingredientsList}
          />
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RecipeDetail;
```

this is where the props for RecipeDetail are coming from:

```
import React from 'react';
import RecipeDetail from './recipeDetail';
import { Jumbotron, ListGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';

const RecipeBoxHolder = ({recipes}) =>{

 const recipesItems = recipes.map((recipe) => {
  console.log(recipes);
   return(
     <RecipeDetail
      key={recipe.recipeName}
      recipe={recipe}
     />
  )
 })
 return(
   <div>
    <Jumbotron className="jtron">
     <h5>Recipes</h5>
      <ListGroup>
       {recipesItems}
      </ListGroup>

    </Jumbotron>
   </div>
  )
}

export default RecipeBoxHolder;
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipeName' of undefined
RecipeDetail.render
src/components/recipeDetail.js:22

```
     19 |   <button
     20 |     className="btn btn-link"
     21 |     onClick={() => {this.setState({isHidden: 
                !this.state.isHidden})}}  >
   > 22 |      {this.props.recipe.recipeName}
     23 |  </button>
     24 | 
     25 | </h5>
```

this comes from a different component where the user enters inputs and its passed to the main parent component for the app

```
    let recipeObject={
       recipeName: this.state.recipe,
       ingredientsList: this.state.ingredients
   };
```

component where user inputs data, takes data and passes it back up to main parent component
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {ListGroupItem} from 'react-bootstrap';

```
class AddModal extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      recipe: '',
      ingredients: ''
    }
  } 


  render(){
  let recipeObject={
  recipeName: this.state.recipe,
  ingredientsList: this.state.ingredients
};

  return(
    <ListGroupItem>
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-header">
         <span>Add Recipe</span> <i className="fas fa-utensils"></i>
       </div>
     <div className="card-body">
        <label>Recipe</label>
       <input value={this.state.recipe} onChange={event => 
           this.setState({recipe: event.target.value})} type="text" 
           className="form-control"/>
       <label className="add-ingredients-label">Add Ingredients</label>
          <textarea value={this.state.ingredients} onChange={event => 
          this.setState({ingredients: event.target.value})} 
          className="form-control"></textarea>
      </div>
         <div className="card-footer">
           <button className="close-button btn btn-outline-danger btn- 
                sm">
           Close
              <i className="fas fa-times"></i>
         </button>
         <button onClick={e =>{this.props.addRecipe(recipeObject)}} 
             className="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm">
            Add Recipe
            <i className="fas fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
         </div>
        </div>
    </ListGroupItem>
    );
  }
 }


 export default AddModal;
```

this is the main parent component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import RecipeBoxHolder from './components/recipeContainer';
import AddModal from './components/addRecipeModal';
import './style/index.css';
import {Button, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';

class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      recipes:[],
      showAddModal: false
    }
  }

  render(){
    const addRecipe = (recipeObject) =>{
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        recipes:[...prevState.recipes, recipeObject]}
      ))
    }

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <RecipeBoxHolder recipes={this.state.recipes} />
        <Button
          bsStyle="primary"
          bsSize="large">
        </Button>
        <AddModal addRecipe={addRecipe} />
      </div>
    ) 
   }
 }


   ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: can you give the ShowRecipe component as well?

Comment: where do you get `this.props.recipe.ingredientsList` ?

Comment: why do you think the props become undefined?

Comment: I think it has something to do with me toggling the ShowRecipe component. It only happens when I click to make that visible. I cant see what would cause that though as the component has its own state

Comment: My question was not clear; I mean: what behaviour do you see?

Comment: So when I add a recipe, the component displays the recipe name that I can go to click on, however, when i click the recipe name, thats when the props become undefined and I get the error. When I log the props before that, I can see the whole props object with no error

Comment: can you describe what exactly happens? I mean: what do you see happening on your screen

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipeName' of undefined"

Comment: in which file/linenumber? better give all the information in the question.

Comment: it comes in line 21 of the recipeDetail component "{this.props.recipe.recipeName}"

Comment: Do you get the recip list from an Async call ?

Comment: Are there multiple recipes in the recipe object with the same name? Can you show us the recipes object?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif 
No, they come from input the user enters in in a different component

Comment: there are multiple recipes, none of them have the same name

Comment: (Nonetheless, you should not use the name as the key, especially not for user input. But that will not solve your issue now.)

Comment: The error message means that `this.props.recipe` is undefined. You have not passed in this prop from the parent component or the variable that you are passing in is also undefined.

Comment: can you show the other component, where the recipeObject array is made?

Comment: The props are passed in the "recipeItems" stateless function, and then only become undefined when I click on the name of the recipe in the "RecipeDetail" component

Comment: just added where its made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Esteban Trevino I put my findings into an answer because the comments become too long, however I do not have a solution as I could not reproduce your issue.

I copied your code into a create-react-app generated react scaffold, and it runs fine. In this gist you can see the file I made:
https://gist.github.com/femans/22324382a8e04390f6a0ece49b867708

I do want to point out that you should not use the recipeName as a key, because they are not unique by design. Better use the following construction:

`const recipesItems = recipes.map((recipe, key) => {
    return(
      <RecipeDetail
        key={key}
        recipe={recipe}
...`

Comment: @esteban-trevino did you figure it out finally?